# Manage users using WebsocketSharp

Tags: authentication, websocket

I'm working on WebsocketSharp and having some difficulties:

1. Is there anyway to handle authentication of websocket based on the
   authentication system on ASP.NET WebAPI, because I'm planning to
   host the WebsocketSharp server in ASP.NET WebAPI.

   **UPDATE** I'm clear this part. They're just 2 seperate apps running on same server. So no interaction back and forth
2. How to get the ID of sender, because I don't see any instruction in its README.md file on github.
3. How to send message to a specific user, or anyway, a specific
   connection ID.  The only example they give is Sessions.Broadcast
   which send to all connected clients.

Websocketsharp github site: https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the questions 2 and 3 websocket-sharp has support for that right out of the box (I am using version 1.0.3-rc11).

In your custom socket class inheriting from WebSocketBehavior you have access to ID property which gives a guid string that represent the current socket connection. By overriding the OnOpen/OnClose/OnMessage handlers you can find appropriate points to interact.

You also have access to a Send method that takes a string or byte array. That will send to the current connection.

If you need to call the socket from other code you need to get hold of the instance of the socket class. From there you can use the Session object as mentioned. It has one Broadcast and also one SendTo method. The latter takes an id that will cause the message to target only that connection.

This will not solve everything. If you ned a mapping between ID and user, then you need to handle that in other ways like suggested by vtortola. But if you really need that I suggest you switch to SignalR that has that inbuilt from the beginning. That will make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot integrate WebSocketSharp in ASP.NET, even if you host it in the same process. It works on his own TCP port, unaware of all the ASP.NET/IIS HTTP modules that work for authentication.

So you will have to do some manual work with cookies/headers yourself, like opening the auth cookie or header used and evaluate it yourself.

For your 2nd and 3rd questions, there are many ways of doing that. It is general programming and not anything particular of websockets. Take a look of this [chat example using WebSockets](https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Chat-application-using-Reactive-Extennsions-(RX)), it will probably give you some ideas.

Comment: However. Because I use a user's database saving passwords in ASP.NET WebAPI. This password was hashed by asp's algorithm when user register. So is there anyway that I can get the plain text password in Websocketsharp, pass it into the hash algorithm that ASP.NET use and then compare it with the stored password hash to mark as authenticated or not ?

Comment: That seems like a very bad idea. You should do the authentication through ASP.NET and then read that authentication cookie from your websocket server to know if the request belongs to an authenticated user. Also if you are using forms authentication, you can put an user id in the encrypted ticket.

Comment: I'm using token based authentication in ASP.NET, which requires client to set Authentication header contain "Bearer [token string]". How to handle in this case ?

Comment: I don't know if you can mess with the headers in WebSocketSharp, you can in mine: https://github.com/vtortola/WebSocketListener/wiki/Hooking-into-the-HTTP-negotiation